# Getting a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, buildpath, jsoup

I am running my app on google app engine. All I have is a simple servlet that is trying to use Jsoup. However when I run the application I get java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jsoup.Jsoup.

I am using Eclipse so I added the jsoup jar file in the Java Build Path -> Libraries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put the Jsoup JAR file in the `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp. That folder is covered by webapp's default classpath. Also, Eclipse will automagically put all libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder in the buildpath of the project, you shouldn't need to do that manually. Of course I assume that the project is been created as *Dynamic Web Project*.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to add the .jar is to right click on your project, and choose **Properties -> Java Build Path**, click the **Libraries** tab, then click **Add External JARs...**  This will allow you to browse to the path of the .jar file you wish to add.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure your `import org.jsoup.Jsoup;` imports are after all the application imports such as 
`import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;`

Having the JSOUP imports before those other imports caused errors for deploying an application at one point for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error now on my Android project. To Fix this on Android, you need to create a lib folder and put the .jar file there